# paypal adaptive payment and permissions

Tags: paypal, sandbox, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

When I use main account, and have two testing accounts I don't have any problems with chained payments because it's a sandbox and both accounts belong to me.

How will it behave in production?

I mean:
- can I define totally random paypal member as the first receiver and myself as second chained?
- When the user has to accept the payment? Because osmetimes I saw that I have to accept the payment form some users and other times I dind't have to. What's the reason for that?
- If a user clicks ' buy ' button on the website do I have to present like summary window first, or can I just use redirects to redirect the user straight ot the paypal account and use redirects again to show the user approve paypal website?